# Add space in between the texts of all the child nodes except the 1st one

Tags: jquery, text, dynamic, whitespace, children

I need to grab the text of all the child nodes on click except the first child's. 
However, when I try to do that, I'm not able to add the space in between the text of 2 child nodes.

For e.g., text of child1 : text 1, text of child2 : text 2, text of child3: text 3.

What I want: text 2 text 3

What I get: text 2text 3

Here's my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.container').click(function(){
  var myText = $(this).children(":not(.nograb)").text();
  console.log(myText);
  });   
});
```

```css
.container{
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <p class="nograb">Don't grab this!</p>
  <p>My text1</p>
  <span>My text2</span>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <p class="nograb">Don't grab this!</p>
  <p>My text3</p>
  <span>My text4</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could populate an array `["My text1", "My text2"]` and than perform a `.join(" ")` operation, which will insert `" "` only **between** the joints :) resulting in this String:

```
"My text1 My text2"
```

```js
$('.container').click(function() {

  var myText = $(this).children(":not(.nograb)").map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
  }).get().join(" ");
  
  console.log(myText);

});
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <p class="nograb">Don't grab this!</p>
  <p>My text1</p>
  <span>My text2</span>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <p class="nograb">Don't grab this!</p>
  <p>My text3</p>
  <span>My text4</span>
</div>
```